# "apt-get install" ends with segmentation fault

Tags: debian, apt

I have a following minimalistic `sources.list` file:

```
root@c:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
root@c:~# apt-get update
Hit http://ftp.fi.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.fi.debian.org wheezy Release
Hit http://ftp.fi.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.fi.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
root@c:~#
```

Now when I try to install a package, I end up with segmentation fault. For example:

```
root@c:~# apt-get install tcpdump
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Segmentation fault
root@c:~#
```

In `/var/log/messages` there is a following entry logged:

```
Mar 29 05:46:25 c kernel: [ 4677.384747] apt-get[5607]: segfault at b8647e30 ip b8647e30 sp bfaaa9c8 error 14
```

The last (sp) number always changes, i.e if I execute `apt-get install nmap` three times, then following is logged:

```
Mar 29 05:46:59 c kernel: [ 4711.046400] apt-get[5612]: segfault at b86cbe30 ip b86cbe30 sp bfb36ea8 error 14
Mar 29 05:47:02 c kernel: [ 4714.229648] apt-get[5616]: segfault at b8609e30 ip b8609e30 sp bfcecec8 error 14
Mar 29 05:47:03 c kernel: [ 4715.505656] apt-get[5620]: segfault at b86dae30 ip b86dae30 sp bfb4b588 error 14
```

I have tried with different repositories and cleaned local repository of retrieved package files. What might cause segment fault when installing a package? Is my `apt-get` broken?

Comment: This is most likely a hardware issue. What is the output of `dpkg -C`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha A hardware issue? Anyway, there is no output for `dpkg -C. Just an exit code 0 so I guess there are no partially installed packages in my system.

Comment: Yes, I can't think of another reason why `apt` would segfault on you. If you want, you could try reinstalling it. `apt-get download apt` (check that this is the same as the version you are using - it should be). Then `dpkg -i apt...deb`.

Comment: Addendum: I'd start with checking your memory and hard drives.

Comment: Does the error reproduces with aptitude: `aptitude install tcpdump` ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using *strace* to diagnose the problem?

I have a similar problem which seems to be related to the google-earth package -- something in the meta-data for the package causes apt-get (or some component of the apt system) to segfault.

I discovered this by using:

```
sudo strace -f apt-get update >log.strace-aptget 2>&1
```

Looking at the log file, I could see that, after reading the file `/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_earth_deb_dists_stable_Release`, apt-get did a `mremap()` which caused a segfault.  I commented out the google-earth entry in sources.list (actually, in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list`) and now apt-get works fine.  (Of course, I now cannot update google-earth, but at least apt-get is working.)

Comment: Any segfault at the software level is a bug. I hope you reported this as an apt bug. If not, please do so. People normally use the `reportbug` to do so.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I had to comment out a virtualbox.org entry.

Answer (score 2):

Run following commands: I got a fix through it.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/locksudo cp -arf /var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/dpkg.backup
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status || sudo cp /var/backups/apt.extended_states.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/available-bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do not know why this worked and nothing else did.

Answer (score 1):

I have started experiencing the same thing in Precise. To workaround this issue I added a file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00bugs which contains one line:

APT::Cache-start    200000000;

The segmentation faults no longer occur. I have opened a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1445436

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a problem with my sources.list by resetting it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt
```

Comment: and i get segmentation fault exactly at this command

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are probably lots of reasons for segfaults. In my case, it was related to a partially installed package. Some commands also gave me `E: The package cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-1-local-10.1.243-418.87.00 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.` while other `apt` commands like `apt search ____` exited with a segfault.

The solution in my case was to do `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-1-local-10.1.243-418.87.00` and then `sudo apt-get update`. After that, my `apt search _____` command worked fine again.